# Is 4/0 copper wire appropriate for a 1200 foot service line?

Tags: electrical

I want to run service wire starting at the utility pole with a meter at pole. From the pole, it will be 1200 ft of buried wire for 200 amp service.

Is two 4/0 copper wires and one 2/0 neutral aluminum uninsulated wire the correct wire necessary?

Comment: No, it's not remotely correct. At 1200 feet, you probably requite a primary extension, whether underground or ~4 more poles to a transformer closer to the point of use. 12-13% drop for 4/0 copper. 1000 kcmil aluminum still has over 6% drop, and copper will cost way too much  and still be over 5% drop. Or, these days, you compare prices and go fully off-grid, since none of it is all that inexpensive.

Comment: Copper will certainly work, but since the power company will be delivering 200A to your meter over AL wire and the price of 2,400' of copper will make your ears bleed, you may as well use AL for the hots, too. You'll have to upsize when choosing AL over CU, but it'll still be cheaper.

Comment: Also, if you're going to bury it, do yourself a big favor and spend the bucks today on conduit. It'll be cheaper should you ever need to do any repair/replacement work, and it'll minimize the chances of your local rodents attempting to make a meal out of your insulation (and requiring said repair/replacement).

Comment: And if you use buried *cable* then it will be a combination that will pretty much always be either all copper or (more likely at the larger sizes) all aluminum. If you use *conduit* then you will use individual wires, not cable, but then you get to pick the sizes - and again the norm is all copper or all aluminum, not a mix.

Comment: Talk to your utility. They're going to need to put a transformer *somewhere*. If they can put it on your property near your building and run 480V instead of 240V over the 1200 feet, that will make a **HUGE** difference.

Comment: is the hige difference in the money expense ?

Comment: Yes. This is the kind of thing that at that distance can make a several thousand dollar difference in total cost. Seriously. I wouldn't expect the utility to actually pay for the wire, but if they can position equipment while you supply the wire (to their specifications), that may save a lot. Actually, even if you have to pay for the transformer it can *still* be cheaper than running larger wire.

Comment: Welcome to DIY. As you can see from the comments your suggested solution might not be the most optimal. If you would edit the question and tell us more about what you want to accomplish and any constraints that limit the possibilities, such as if the utility is unwilling to build an extension to a new service point, then we could give better advice as to an alternative.

Comment: The differences can be in the 10s of thousands of dollars...

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is it you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 7):

Running 120/240V wire is not viable at your distance without parallels.  It actually broke my voltage drop calculator.  If you are violently committed to copper because of some superstition, I think I can cure that: the price tag will be $120,000 at least.

So, aluminum??? With 2 parallels you can go 600 kcmil aluminum x 6 ($27,000). 3 parallels will be 350 kcmil x 9 ($25,000). 4 parallels will be 250 kcmil x 12 ($24,000).   Yeah, aluminum isn't working either.  This is ridiculous.

Several people seem to be offering 480V,  50 kVA transformers at $2500 a pop.  So we get 2 of those and kick voltage up to 480V for the long haul. Now we only need two 250 kcmil aluminum wires ($4000).  That's a lot better, we're at $9000 plus two concrete pads - cheaper still if we can get the utility to provide 480V so we only need 1 transformer.

It would be a bit better if you could get 600V transformers, as you'd get a small wire shrink to 3/0 aluminum ($3000).  But 600V transformers are not commodities so may be more costly.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's ridiculous to even entertain this type of question. The OP needs to talk to the utility. They have their own rules, and they answer this type of question all the time. In my area, they'll send a field rep to speak with you and hammer some sense into your head. But when it comes to installation, they will only talk with a licensed electrician, and all permits must be pulled. So the OP also needs to talk to an electrician, and then the electrician is the one running numbers and presenting alternatives.

Comment: @Cheery True. But at least this gives OP some idea of what they're up against. And if they talk to an electrician and the electrician doesn't know about how to do this with transformers then they right away know they need a different electrician.

Comment: @Cheery yeah, obviously.... that's why I didn't deep-dive into the nuts and bolts of  how to wire step-up transformers.   This is a procurement question.  And what you do with it on your side of the meter is your business. Put up a ranch panel with a 50A RV outlet and a 20A GFCI outlet, and the utility hooks it up and goes away. What you put on the thru-lugs later is between you and your AHJ, unless solar or large EV charging is involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to come up with money for your unsuitably small wire sizes, looks like about $15,000 for wire alone, since you were buying copper 4/0 (and it's too small, and no conduit and no trench...both are additional costs) which will buy quite a bit of off-grid power production and storage. **Without** a power bill (but with some maintenance expense over time.)

Expensive long-distance power connections have long been a reason to go "off-grid" and in the current era, the price of power production has come vastly down from where it used to be. It's well-worth taking a serious look at whether you want to connect to the power grid at all, given the length of your connection and the inherent expenses involved in making that long-distance connection.